# How to escape hash character in URL

Tags: html, http, escaping, query-string

How can I escape the `#` hash sign (sometimes known as number sign or pound sign) sent in the query string of a URL?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

[Percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Replace the hash with `%23`.

Comment: Useful if you want to share a url which contains '#' to twitter

Comment: This doesn't work on Chrome 74. Furthermore, `encodeURI('#');` is returning `#` and not the percent encoded character

Comment: `#` is a valid URI character, but it starts the [hash fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), so you need to encode it in the query string.  Compare `encodeURIComponent('#')`.  What do you see in Chrome 74?

Comment: You must also encode a `#` anywhere in a `data:` URL, otherwise it will be treated as a fragment identifier.