# Url with special char #

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I've to show with a browser some files that contains this # on the name. Using it on the url the file seems to be not available.

How can I configure IIS or my web.config to allow this?

thanks,
Andrea

Comment: @Mr47 - this question is a duplicate, but because of the `#` it's hard to find.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how URLs work.

The `#` character is used to denote the hash portion; anything after it is not sent to the server.

You need to escape the `#` as `%23`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [URLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) method to encode the filename for the querystring

As mentioned, the # character is a special character to denote a bookmark on a page

Answer (score 2):

You need to [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) the file name as you build your URL. This will escape the '#' character, allowing the browser to interpret it appropriately.

Proper encoding is very important for preventing [Cross-Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) attacks against your application, which can be devastating.