# How to get parameter from url?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been developing a PHP page using Code Igniter. There is some function from controller:

```
public function language_testing($language_code, $logout=0)
{      
      echo ($language_code);
      //come actions
}
```

And I'm trying to send the following url: `http://mypage.com/index.php/controller/language_testing/bg#9`

But my function shows me "bg" instead of "bg#9". Please, tell me, how can I get a content after "#"? I need it so much.

Answer (score 1):

You should be posting to the following URL to get the value to appear in `$logout`:

```
http://mypage.com/index.php/controller/language_testing/bg/9
```

Otherwise, the data after the pound sign isn't accessible by the server.

Comment: It doesn't come up at all - anchors are strictly client side.

Comment: You mean there are no ways to send content with #?

Answer (score 1):

http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
$urlComp=parse_url($yourURL);
echo $urlComp['fragment'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `#` is a HTML bookmark, used to redirect focus around a page using IDs on HTML elements. Browsers won't submit this as part of a URL to the server.

Depending on your rewrite rules, you'll either want to create a link that's semantically pleasing, like `http://site.com/path/index.php/bg/9` or as `http://site.com/path/index.php?bg=9` (which is what your rewrite rules would be achieving anyway).

Note if you really need the `#` sign to be submitted for some reason then you'll need to submit it using `%23` in the URL (@jth_92 beat me to it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the function params add one more parameter for code as well

```
public function language_testing($language, $code , $logout=0){      
  echo ($language);
  echo ($code);
  //come actions
```

}

and call it just like
     http://mypage.com/index.php/controller/language_testing/bg/9

it will resolve your problem and then you can concatenate both values

Answer (score 0):

The # is an HTML entity that is used in anchor tags to jump to a name reference. For example:

```
<a href="#test">Jump to test on page</a>
<a name="test">Test</a>
```

Thus, it is not being interpreted as part of your parameter. You should be able to use bg%23 as %23 is the escape character for hashing.

http://mypage.com/index.php/controller/language_testing/bg%239

[How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)