# Special characters in jsp request parameter are not read properly in spring controller

Tags: spring, jsp, url, spring-mvc

i am trying to send some parameter in jsp request parameter which contains special character like '#' Ex:

```
http://localhost:8080/studentenrollmentsystem/editenrolment?id=3&course=C#&name=YASHIKA&dob=1986-12-22 00:00:00.0
```

In the spring controller when i try to access the parameter named course it gives only C in respect of C# plus the name parameter is not captured. please help how can i implement this functionality properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape Hash character in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Comment: i know i have to add %23 for # in url, but my question was how to convert it into such form. Is there any tag lib which can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<spring:url>` tag.

Specify the taglib directive at the top of your JSP (if not already specified):

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

And then you can use it something like this:

```
<spring:url value="http://localhost:8080/studentenrollmentsystem/editenrolment?id=3&course={course}&name=YASHIKA&dob=1986-12-22 00:00:00.0">
    <spring:param name="course" value="C#"/>
</spring:url>
```

Splitting out the course as a `<spring:param>` will ensure it gets escaped - and so the full URL will look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/studentenrollmentsystem/editenrolment?id=3&course=C%23&name=YASHIKA&dob=1986-12-22 00:00:00.0
```

More info on the tag library [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am using it as follows and working fine.
<spring:url value="editenrolment?id=${enrolmentdetail.studentId}&name=${enrolmentdetail.studentFirstName}&dob=${enrolmentdetail.studentDOB}" var="link">
         <spring:param name="course" value="${enrolmentdetail.subjectName}" />
      </spring:url>
     <a href="${link}">Edit</a>
     /<a href="${link}">Delete</a>