# htaccess credentials in URL when password contains a hash #

Tags: url, selenium

Using Selenium I am accessing protected pages. I need to put the credentials into the URL to prevent the .htaccess popup from appearing. This is the method suggested in Selenium documentation.

One of the locations I need to access has a hash character in the password, and this causes the browser (both Chrome and Firefox) to not understand the URL and treat it as a search term.

e.g. http://user:pass@example.com/ gets through, but `http://user:pa#ss@example.com/` is not recognised as a URL.

How can I "encode" the hash?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I'm using Scala, but the language is not relevant. This is a problem that can be seen by manually typing the URL.

Comment: Gotcha. Does replacing the hash with `%23` helps?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Pop in an answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to encode the hash with `%23`.

See also:

- [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)