# Put hash in telephone link in html5

Tags: html

I have tried to put hash in tel link in html5 like this

```
<a href="tel:*166#">click</a>
```

when i use it in the android and click on it i get *166 without the #
how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried [`%23`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url) in stead of `#` ?

( And [`%2A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in stead of `*` ? )