# how can I use # character in url for rest webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, get, jersey

I have a url with below pattern for passing data with get method to my rest web server developed by jersey:
http://localhost:8080/myprojectName/resrtApp/request?Name=$Name&LastName=$LastName&Message=$Message&UserId=$UserId

when I used '#' character in the end of Message field, the UserId field, passed null to web server. how can I fix this problem? I have to use # sign in the end of Message!!

this is my code for getting parameters:

```
@POST
@Path("/request")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML + ";charset=utf-8")
public UserResponse getUsers(@QueryParam("Name") String Name,
                               @QueryParam("LastName") String LastName,
                               @QueryParam("Message") String Message,
                               @QueryParam("UserId") String UserId
) {
```

// simple code
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape hash character in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Comment: how can I replace # with %23 in my application?

Comment: I'm not sure what objects you are manipulating since you have not posted your code. If your URL is in a `String`, then you may use the `replaceAll` method. For example `url.replaceAll("#", "%23");`

Comment: I edited the question for adding my code, I don't know where should I replace the url?

Comment: I believe you have posted some server-side code. `#` must be escaped on the client side.