# CSS Button Link - Non-Anchor Hastag URL

Tags: html, css

I've seen a few answers which had code that prevents the hastag location jump in URLs for links that appear in Java or HTML5, but I haven't seen anything specific to a button link. 
I have a customized button acting as a link to a URL that leads to a contact form. The URL address has a "#" in it, and when the action of clicking on the button is performed, it travels to the URL link but stops at the point of the URL which contains the "#". I am presuming this is because it is treating it as an anchor location.

Code used is below:

```
<form action="/portal/index#/accounts/enroll" method="get">
<button class="my_linkable_button"> Request StudyTRAX </button>
</form>
```

Thanks!
-pm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape hash character in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Comment: Yes, check the link above and try this : action="/portal/index%23/accounts/enroll"

Comment: I replaced the # with "%23", but now the button returns a page not found error. Oddly, it says the exact page URL I am trying to link to cannot be found. When I link just regular text to the URL it works without issue.