# # (hash) in text value reaks havoc with my jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am opening a jquery dialog with the following steps.

```
   var vFrm = document.getElementById("addressValidationFrame");

   vFrm.src = "../Address%20Validation.aspx?address=" + addrVal + "&city=" 
               + cityVal + "&state=" + stateVal + "&zip=" + zipVal 
               + "&type=" + type;

   $("#dialogAV").dialog({
     modal: true, title: vFrmName, width: 600, height: 400, resizable: false,
     close: function (event, ui) {
                        vFrm.src = "";
                        $(this).dialog("destroy");
                        __doPostBack();
                    }
    });
```

In the `Address%20Validation.Page_Load()` I Request the posted values:

```
  String validationType = Request.QueryString["type"].ToString();

  String addrParam = Request.QueryString["address"].ToString();
```

Address Validation would then go on to use the FedEx address validation 
service to validate the submitted address (city,state,zip not shown here).

All was working without a problem until I ran into a submitted "address" 
that contained a #(hash) character. The presence of the # character seems
perfectly normal as part of an address (for room/apt/suite numbers), so I 
expect to run into these frequently.

With a #, an exception is thrown when Request'ing the first parameter "type".
I tried substituting the html code for # => &#35:

```
...?address=" + addVal.replace(/#/g,"&#35;") + ...
```

...but to no avail. I still get an object null reference exception on the 
first Request.QueryString call. To keep developing other parts of my process,
I settled on this:

```
...?address=" + addVal.replace(/#/g,"Suite ") + ...
```

..which I am not particularly proud of.
I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Is this any help?  Not 100% sure it will be.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url

Comment: Will miracles never cease? It did in fact work. Now using ....+ addrVal.replace(/#/g, "%23")... THANKS!

Comment: Great! Your welcome.