# Handle illegal URI characters in xslt inclusion

Tags: java, xslt, uri, xsl-fo, invalid-characters

In a xsl transformation I have a xslt file that includes some other xslt. The problem is that the URI for these xslt contains illegal characters, in particular '##'. The xslt looks like this:

`<xsl:include href="/appdm/tomcat/webapps/sentys##1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/xslt/release_java/xslt/gen.xslt" />`

and when I try to instantiate a java `Transformer` I get the error:

`javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: org.apache.xml.utils.URI$MalformedURIException: Fragment contains invalid character:#`

This is the java code:

```java
public String xslTransform2String(String sXml, String sXslt) throws Exception {
    String sResult = null;
    try {
        Source oStrSource = createStringSource(sXml);

        DocumentBuilderFactory oDocFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        oDocFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

        //sXslt is the xslt content with the inclusions 
        //<xsl:include href="/appdm/tomcat/webapps/sentys##1.0.0/WEB-INF/classes/xslt/release_java/xslt/gen.xslt" />"
        Document oDocXslt = oDocFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sXslt)));
        Source oXsltSource = new DOMSource(oDocXslt);

        StringWriter oStrOut = new StringWriter();
        Result oTransRes = createStringResult(oStrOut);
        Transformer oTrans = createXsltTransformer(oXsltSource);

        oTrans.transform(oStrSource, oTransRes);
        sResult = oStrOut.toString();
    } catch (Exception oEx) {
        throw new BddException(oEx, XmlProvider.ERR_XSLT, null);
    }
    return sResult;
}

private Transformer createXsltTransformer(Source oXsltSource) throws Exception {
    Transformer transformer = getXsltTransformerFactory().newTransformer(
            oXsltSource);
    ErrorListener errorListener = new DefaultErrorListener();
    transformer.setErrorListener(errorListener);

    return transformer;
}
```

is there a way I can go with relative paths instead of absolute path?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check if that is the real path containing ##, not modified accidentally?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the real path on a Unix File System. It is given from the versioning system of the customer to the application WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the MalformedURIException, replace the second or both `#` with `%23`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5007362/4092205