# How to use '#' symbol in URI?

Tags: url, ftp, uri

In URI '#' is reserved for fragment-id but I have a situation where my password contains a '#' character which is not being recognized by URI. Given below is the piece of the code. What needs to be done?

```
ftpfs.initialize(new URI("ftp://username:password@host"), conf);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but even after URL encoding it is not recognizing ' # ' in the password. Could you please suggest me how to do it?

Comment: What language is this? Give us an MCVE
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked out.