# display a image that starts with a # in <img> tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, image

```
<?php
$imageDir = "";
$images = glob($imageDir . '*.jpg');
foreach ($images as $image) {
?> 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <?php
    $name = chop($image, '.jpg');
    $filename = $image;
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        $taken = "Screenshot Taken: " . date("F d Y H:i:s", filemtime($filename));
    }
    ?>
    <a data-gallery="example-gallery" style="text-decoration:none" href="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="d-block mb-4 h-100" data-toggle="lightbox" data-title="Player Name: <?php echo $name; ?>" data-footer="<?php echo $taken; ?>" data-max-width="800" >                            
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="">
        <p><?php echo $name; ?></p>
    </a>
</div><?php}?>
```

Hi . i created a image gallery with php . using glob function. but some images wont display , because those images starts with a #(hash) . EX: www.mysite.com/ss/#insta.jpg
iam using  tags . is there any other way to view images like this in a

> < img> tag

.
[image]

Comment: Hmmm. does the image even display when you go to `www.mysite.com/ss/#insta.jpg`? The browser shouldn't even send a request for anything after the #. Are you sure the actual image is not accessible without #?

Comment: probably a bad idea to allow a # in the file name

Comment: icant view the image even from the browser. these images are screenshots of the players . some players starts their name with # or other symbols .. thts why i cant change the name of the image file .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode the `#` in your URL
Replacing it with `%23` should work

Comment: Yep. Thank You. i used str_replace(). And it worked .