# Angular (keyup) event not detecting only # symbol

Tags: html, angular

Im trying to implement search bar using angular (keyup) event.And i have file name like

- base @,
- base $,
- base 1,
- base #,
- base 2,

when i search base @ or base $ or base 1 in the search bar it filters fine. but when i search base # it dont filter base # it filter all file name with base.
here is the code below which i have coded

My html:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search file" (keyup)="onSearch($event)" [(ngModel)]='searchKeywords'>
```

my js code:

```
onSearch(event: any) {
    const keywords = event.target.value;
    if (keywords && keywords.length > 2) {
          const apiURL =`abc/thg/hjy?filter[file.name]=${keywords}`;
          this.api.get(apiURL).subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.topics = data.list;
            if (this.trigger) {
            this.trigger.openMenu();
            }
         });
    } else {
        this.topics = [];
        this.trigger.closeMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: It should not happen, probably you missed `"` after keyup event attribute `(keyup)="onSearch($)"`

Comment: @PankajParkar that wasnt the issue. it works fine for other special symbols.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code. It is problem with # because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier in URI. Thus, the character "#" should be excluded in that are passed in the URL.  So base will be treated as null

Comment: @techyaura so there is no way that  i can pass # in the URl??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Now I'm able to pass `#` .

```js
onSearch(event: any) {
  const keywords = event.target.value;
  const params: any = {};
  if (keywords && keywords.length > 2) {
    params['filter[translations.title]'] = keywords;
    const options = {
      search: params
    };
    const apiURL = `abc/thg/hjy`;
    this.api.get(apiURL, options).subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.topics = data.list;
      if (this.trigger) {
        this.trigger.openMenu();
      }
    });
  } else {
    this.topics = [];
    this.trigger.closeMenu();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have an **missing** in the HTML markup.

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search file" (keyup)="onSearch($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchKeywords">
```

Then, in the `.ts` file:

```js
onSearch(event: any) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: D that wasnt the issue. i have edited my question now. can you check now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the value is getting set ok in `apiURL` in the line:

```
const apiURL =`abc/thg/hjy?filter[file.name]=${keywords}`;
```

I think the problem is the following line, where you are passing the # (hashtag) without URL encoding it.

Try swapping out the hashtag with `%23` before you use it in the next line - your `get` request.

See: [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)