# # character gets ignored when a call to api it's made

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how can I do that # character should not be ignored when executing an api call.. I tried to use encodeURI and encodeURIComponent but still gets ignored and the api it's returning the response like I didn't use # at all. I mention that all other characters like $@!~` are not ignored, only this one # . Any hint will be appreciated.
The service looks like this:

```
service.getCarByCarNumber = async car_number => {
  const carsReq = {
    headers: fetchApi.newHeaderWithToken(CAR_JWT, SITE_ID)
  };
  const result = await instance.get(
    `${API_GATEWAY_URL}${CAR_ENDPOINT}/carByNumber/${car_number}`,
    carsReq
  );

  return formatCarSearchRes(car);
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape hash character in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url)

Comment: this is what encodeURIComponent does and still gets ignored by the API. My problem is that I have a search input and I need to search something by number, so when I type the number, the api gets called and returns the response. If I type 01234#, the api doesn't recognize # and returns the response like I typed 01234. If I use encodeURIComponent, the api gets called with 01234%23 but acts the same like above. So practically, this is my issue.

Comment: Can you please provide an example (a complete URL)? What you send to the API and what the API returns?

Comment: ok, so this is the request url http://localhost:3000/online/api/car/carByNumber/S0152%23 when I search by S0152# and returns the response like I've typed only S0152, without #. I've edited the post with the service code.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your client side code, as encodeURIComponent returns %23. What framework is your api written in? If It's written in express you can access the requested url by writing `req.originalUrl || req.url`. Can you please check if the API receives the #?

Comment: It's in express yes, in service I checked and it's received # also. If I search for 1234#, the service receives 1234#.

Comment: can you show the url that the api returns? and how it should look like as well? I think what's missing is, the api must convert the hash symbol back to a %23, but doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218915/discussion-between-christian-and-keimeno).