# How can I include '#' in my telegram BOT message?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I was trying to send a message through my telegram bot and the bot is working fine. The only problem is that the message body does not include the text after the character '#'.

So, if you are trying to send a message "Stack # Overflow". The message received is "Stack ".

```
const messageBody = `\n<strong>Send message</strong>\n
    <b>Journey details</b>
    <b>Estimated Distance: </b>${data.journeyDetails.estimatedDistance}
    <b>Estimated Time: </b>${data.journeyDetails.estimatedTime}
    <b>Pickup Address: </b>${data.journeyDetails.pickupAddress}
    <b>Drop Address: </b>${data.journeyDetails.dropAddress}\n
    `;

  await sendTelegramMessage(
    `${TELEGRAM_HOST}${TELEGRAM_API_ACCESS_KEY}/sendMessage?parse_mode=html&chat_id=${telegramChatId}&text=${messageBody}`
  );
```

Sometimes the pickup and drop address contains '#'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HTML, thus you need to escape the #-charcter. You could use `%23` instead of `#` or use the function `encodeURI(yourMessage)`.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007352/how-to-escape-hash-character-in-url) for reference.